# Split spreadsheet into pieces based on the sequences of numbers

Tags: python, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a dataset in spreadsheets, which is basically the data about every trip of the train in New York Subway.

```
╔═══════╦══════╦══════════════╦════════════════╦═════════╦═══════════════╦══════════════════╗
║ trip  ║  id  ║ arrival_time ║ departure_time ║ stop_id ║ stop_sequence ║     Station      ║
╠═══════╬══════╬══════════════╬════════════════╬═════════╬═══════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:06:00      ║ 0:06:00        ║     237 ║             1 ║ Penn Station     ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:18:00      ║ 0:18:00        ║     214 ║             2 ║ Woodside         ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:23:00      ║ 0:23:00        ║      55 ║             3 ║ Forest Hills     ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:25:00      ║ 0:25:00        ║     107 ║             4 ║ Kew Gardens      ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:29:00      ║ 0:32:00        ║     102 ║             5 ║ Jamaica          ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:47:00      ║ 0:47:00        ║     183 ║             6 ║ Rockville Centre ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:50:00      ║ 0:50:00        ║     225 ║             7 ║ Baldwin          ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:53:00      ║ 0:53:00        ║      64 ║             8 ║ Freeport         ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:56:00      ║ 0:56:00        ║     226 ║             9 ║ Merrick          ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 0:59:00      ║ 0:59:00        ║      16 ║            10 ║ Bellmore         ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:02:00      ║ 1:02:00        ║     215 ║            11 ║ Wantagh          ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:05:00      ║ 1:05:00        ║     187 ║            12 ║ Seaford          ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:07:00      ║ 1:07:00        ║     136 ║            13 ║ Massapequa       ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:09:00      ║ 1:09:00        ║     135 ║            14 ║ Massapequa Park  ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:12:00      ║ 1:12:00        ║       8 ║            15 ║ Amityville       ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:15:00      ║ 1:15:00        ║      38 ║            16 ║ Copiague         ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:18:00      ║ 1:18:00        ║     117 ║            17 ║ Lindenhurst      ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_2 ║ 1:23:00      ║ 1:23:00        ║      27 ║            18 ║ Babylon          ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_3 ║ 1:00:00      ║ 1:00:00        ║      27 ║             1 ║ Babylon          ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_3 ║ 1:05:00      ║ 1:05:00        ║     117 ║             2 ║ Lindenhurst      ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_3 ║ 1:08:00      ║ 1:08:00        ║      38 ║             3 ║ Copiague         ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_3 ║ 1:10:00      ║ 1:10:00        ║       8 ║             4 ║ Amityville       ║
║ GO505 ║ 20_3 ║ 1:13:00      ║ 1:13:00        ║     135 ║             5 ║ Massapequa Park  ║
╚═══════╩══════╩══════════════╩════════════════╩═════════╩═══════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

I need to split it somehow into the parts based on the sequences in stop_sequence. Each sequence from 1 to n (here, 18) means 1 trip of the train. So, for example, I need to count the time of each trip (which is departure_time of each last stop_sequence - arrival_time of the first stop_sequence) for each trip (There are about 5,000 of them). How can I somehow do it? I wish I could split the column in python with pandas into several trips and calculate the time for each trip. But I do not know how to do it.

My expected output is

trip id  ║  Duration of the trip

GO505 20_2  ║  x:xx:xx

GO505 20_3  ║  x:xx:xx

I am new in data science. Please help!

Comment: can you just select lines matching an id? It would work with your example

Comment: @B.Go there are about 5 thousand of ids not related to each other. so it is not the best way

Comment: OK. My other idea would be to make a regular expression matching all up to 18 (Babylon or Penn station (I guess)), and taking the array of all the matches !?

Comment: @B.Go haha, it is not possible too, as sometimes there are 18, 17 or 22  stations even in the same route :(

Comment: I guess there is always >1 station!? But are the ending points always the same 2 cities?

Comment: ie find >1 and  (Babylon or Penn station)

Comment: @B.Go nope, the ending points are different as there are more than 30 thousand measurement

Comment: can you post your expected output

Comment: by the way, to get the trip lengths, reading all line in order would work, and you can even build your splits at the same time. ie reading all lines in order IS a way to split your data correctly (split after each stop_sequence goes back to 0)!

Comment: maybe you can build a regular expression from a trip name with stop_sequence = 1 and all the next line with stop_sequence >1 ? Is the trip name constant? what is the separator between columns?

Comment: @B.Go Yes, I wanted to split data after each stop_sequence goes back to 1. How can I do it in python, that's my question as I have no idea

Comment: doesn't work in notepad++, but with spaces as column separators, something like this would work in MULTILINE mode: (GO505 +[0-9_]+ +[0-9:]+ +[0-9:]+ +[0-9]+ +1 + [A-Za-z ]+ +$)(GO505 +[0-9_]+ +[0-9:]+ +[0-9:]+ +[0-9]+ +([2-9]|[1-9][0-9]+) + [A-Za-z ]+ +$)+

Comment: you may need to put an expression for the trip name, too, and/or use some kind of \n instead of $

Comment: you may also need an extra set of () around that to capture it as a single group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Range A:G -> the data about every trip of the train**

**Cell I1:**`=QUERY({ArrayFormula(A:A&" "&B:B),ArrayFormula(VALUE(C:D))},"select Col1,max(Col3)-min(Col2) where Col1!=' ' group by Col1 label max(Col3)-min(Col2) 'Duration of the trip' format max(Col3)-min(Col2) 'hh:mm:ss'")`

[image]

**Function References**

- [Query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)